# setPaint() not working when trying to use Gradient Paint

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paint

I am very new to Java and working on a GUI that draws shapes. This is an example of my class for drawing Circles. I need to add the ability for it to draw shapes with a color gradient. It seems like the only way to call setPaint() is in the paint method. It will not recognize the method in my drawShape(Graphics g) method. Is there a way to work around this? I want to be able to call it in the class.

```
    import java.awt.BasicStroke;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.GradientPaint;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Paint;
    import java.io.Serializable;


public class Oval extends Shape implements Serializable {

    //Default constructor
    public Oval() {

    }

    //Constructor
    public Oval(int c1, int c2, int c3, int c4, int c5, int c6, int c7, boolean d, boolean f, int tran, int s, String ss, boolean g, Color ccc1, Color ccc2) {
        component1 = c1;
        component2 = c2;
        component3 = c3;
        component4 = c4;
        red = c5;
        green = c6;
        blue = c7;
        dashed = d;
        thick = false;
        fill = f;
        trans = tran;
        stroke = s;
        textBox = ss;
        gFlag = g;
        cc1 = ccc1;
        cc2 = ccc2;

    }

    @Override
    public void drawShape(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue, trans));

        if (gFlag == true) {

            Graphics g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            GradientPaint gp2 = new GradientPaint(0, 0, cc1, 10, 10, cc2);
            //Error
            g2d.setPaint(gp2);

        } else if (dashed == true && fill != true) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            float[] fa = {10, 10, 10};
            BasicStroke bs = new BasicStroke(stroke, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 10, fa, 10);

            g2d.setStroke(bs);
            g2d.drawOval(component1, component2, component3, component4);

        } else if (dashed != true && fill != true) {

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            BasicStroke bs = new BasicStroke(stroke);
            g2d.setStroke(bs);
            g2d.drawOval(component1, component2, component3, component4);

        } else if (fill == true) {
            g.fillOval(component1, component2, component3, component4);
            System.out.println("FILLED OVAL DRAWN");
        }

        System.out.println("Oval Drawn.");
    }

    Shape copy() {

        return new Oval();

    }

}
```

Comment: Issue is not with the flag, it is due to the fact that the setPaint method is not recognized if it is not in the paint method.

Comment: Sorry, reading on phone 

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

The [`Graphics2D.setPaint(Paint)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setPaint-java.awt.Paint-) method is part of the `Graphics2D` class, **not** the `Graphics` class. The drawing instance passed to a paint method for Swing components will typically be a `Graphics2D` object. I.E. It can be cast to a `Graphics2D` instance.